# How to generate sequence using LSTM?

Tags: python, keras, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I want to generate a sequence when a particular input is activated. I want to generate odd or even sequence according to its corresponding input neuron activation. I am trying to create a model using LSTM because it can remember the short term order.

I tried this way

```
import numpy as np
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense,LSTM


X=np.array([[1,0],
            [0,1]])

Y=np.array([[1,3,5,7,9],
            [2,4,6,8,10]])

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(10, input_shape=(2))
model.add(LSTM(5, return_sequences=True))
model.add(LSTM(5, return_sequences=False))
model.add(Dense(5))
model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer='adam')

model.fit(X,Y)
```

But when I tried to fit the model its giving me this error

> NameError: name 'model' is not defined

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To use RNNs in Keras you need to introduce an additional dimension into your data: The timesteps. In your case you want to have 5 timesteps. Because you want to have a one-to-many relationship between input and output data you need to replicate the input data 5 times. The last `LSTM` layer must also be set to return sequences, since you want a result for every timestep and not just the last one. To make the `Dense` Layers aware of the time dimension you need to wrap them with the `TimeDistributed` layer. And the last Dense layer only has one output, since it will output only one result for each timestep.

```
import numpy as np
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense,LSTM
from keras.layers.wrappers import TimeDistributed

X=np.array([[[1, 0],
        [1, 0],
        [1, 0],
        [1, 0],
        [1, 0]],

       [[0, 1],
        [0, 1],
        [0, 1],
        [0, 1],
        [0, 1]]])


Y=np.array([[[ 1],
        [ 3],
        [ 5],
        [ 7],
        [ 9]],

       [[ 2],
        [ 4],
        [ 6],
        [ 8],
        [10]]])


model = Sequential()
model.add(TimeDistributed(Dense(10), input_shape=(5, 2)))
model.add(LSTM(5, return_sequences=True))
model.add(LSTM(5, return_sequences=True))
model.add(TimeDistributed(Dense(1)))
model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer='adam')

model.fit(X,Y, nb_epoch=4000)

model.predict(X)
```

With this I get after about 4000 epochs the following result:

```
Epoch 4000/4000
2/2 [==============================] - 0s - loss: 0.0032
Out[20]:
array([[[ 1.02318883],
        [ 2.96530271],
        [ 5.03490496],
        [ 6.99484348],
        [ 9.00506973]],

       [[ 2.05096436],
        [ 3.96090508],
        [ 5.98824072],
        [ 8.0701828 ],
        [ 9.85805798]]], dtype=float32)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply,Is there a better way to predict next sequences  `[[11,13,15,17,19],[12,14,16,18,20]]` without training with this sequence

Answer (score 1):

Change the `model.add(Dense(10, input_shape=(2))` to

```
model.add(Dense(10, input_shape=(2,)))

model.add(Dense(5)) # Remove this
```

Note below both code are equivalent:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(32, input_shape=(2,)))

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(32, input_dim=2))
```